# Jinja2 - out-of-loop incremental counter

Tags: python, jinja2

I'd like to have a template with such a tag (named `dont_know_what` here):

```
Paragraph {% dont_know_what %}
Something written.
Paragraph {% dont_know_what %}
Some other text.
Paragraph {% dont_know_what %}
Again.
```

rendering:

```
Paragraph 1
Something written.
Paragraph 2
Some other text.
Paragraph 3
Again.
```

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Can you not just use a forloop ?

Comment: @karthikr I edited the question, it was maybe not clear. Is a forloop still relevant? Plus: I have limited editing ability on the text (I am parsing an already existing document) hence the question

Comment: Can you parse your document into JSON before you render the template, or is in that format already?

Comment: @Nickel not sure to get what you mean. It's plain text, but I could indeed parse it and hierarchize it. Finally I guess the answer is that it's much easier to regex this task out instead of using jinja...